# Circle symbol while typing in Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, office365

A black circle is appearing under the cursor when I type something inside an Excel cell (see picture below). I have occasionally seen it appear in Word as well. It seems to be a "touch handle", designed to make it easier to grab with a touchscreen. However, I never use touch and Excel is in "mouse mode" (as opposed to "touch mode").

Would anyone know how to remove it?

Additional info:

- Microsoft Office 365 Business, version 2001 (build 12430.20184 Click-to-Run)
- Excel is in Mouse Mode, not Touch Mode – however, my computer does have a touchscreen (which I never use and was not being used when the screenshot was taken).

[image: Circle]

Comment: where is the cursor when this appears ?

Comment: Can you click and drag it, or double-click it?

Comment: @PeterH it is under the cursor. Searching for "black circle under cursor" makes me think that this is a touch feature. I have edited my question from "what is it" to "how do I get rid of it". Thanks!

Comment: @harrymc I can't. Everything behaves as if it were not here (if I click on it, I actually just click on the cell behind the circle).

Answer (score 1):

Look under "Options -> Ease of access -> provide feedback with animation", turn that off and it's gone

Answer (score 0):

The Scroll Lock button (ScrLk) on your keyboard might be on; try turning it off. This went away for me once I did that.

Answer (score 0):

When editing a cell on right of screen where the cell in question is not fully visible; the entire sheet scrolls/shifts to the left to display entire cell.  If you decrease the magnification of the sheet such that the entire cell is visible (before editing) on the screen, the circle in question does not appear.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue as described by Alexandre d'Entraigues (I have Microsoft Office 365 home version) and additionally during the same session, the formula bar didn't show the content of the cells when moving with keyboard arrows from cell to cell (no formulas involved, just text). I saw the text of certain cell on formula bar only if I double-clicked on the cell. Restarting the Excel resolved both problems.

Answer (score -2):

It went away when I touched an empty cell on my touch screen. I don't what caused it but this seemed to get rid of it. In the past I just restarted excel and that worked for me too.